# Individual DB operations in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

We use Hibernate as the JPA implementation. We have the following code:

```
new managedObject();
managedObject.var1 = 1;
myRepository.save(managedObject);
managedObject.var2 = 2;
myRepository.save(managedObject);
managedObject.var3 = 3;
myRepository.save(managedObject);

entityManager.flush(); //Causes a single insert statement to be sent to DB
```

The flush causes the cumulative record to be inserted into the DB. We are instead looking for a way by which the three saves will cause three different SQL commands to be sent to the DB. One insert followed by 2 updates. We need this so that a database trigger detects the changes to the record. Regardless of the merits and demerits of triggers, is there a configuration or setting of JPA/Hibernate that can make this possible? I want to avoid calling flush after each save because there may be other entities that I have modified before the save but not shown in the sample code.

Comment: Logically, there is a single change: this transaction sets the var3 of the object to 3. Whether the algorithm to get there sets it to 1 and 2 in the same transaction before is an implementation details. The atomic unit of work is the transaction, and this unit of work consists in creating a managedObject with a var3 set to 3. Are you sure you shouldn't have 3 different transactions, if you want 3 atomic changes?

Comment: I want this to be a single Transaction or UOW. Yet I want the transaction to carry 3 SQL operations, corresponding to the 3 saves that have been performed on the repository.